# Laravel 4 controller tests - ErrorException after too many $this->call() - why?

Tags: testing, controller, phpunit, laravel, laravel-4

I'd greatly appreciate some help regarding a Laravel 4 issue I'm experiencing.

I'm testing controller routes, specifically a controller that is responsible for routing responses for a questionnaire. I'm testing scenarios such as: the user attempting to skip a question, the user requesting a question that doesn't exist... etc.

The tests that I've written for all scenarios up until now work as expected using PHPunit. The test I'm currently writing involves several `$this->call()` or `$this->client->request()` executions and that's where things break down. If I execute `$this->call()` or `$this->client->request()` too many times (2 or more to be specific) in a single test method I get an ErrorException in the terminal:

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined variable: header","file":"/Volumes/Dev HD/dmh/app/views/layouts/steps.php","line":1}}

If I reduce the quantity of `$this->call()` or `$this->client->request()` in the test method to one, things work, and no exception is shown. I've been using the following code:

### Code

```
/**
 * When the user skips questions they have not yet answered, the user 
 * should be redirected back to the first unanswered question.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testDiscoverSkipQuestions()
{
    // Get the first question.
    $domCrawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'style/discover');

    // Answer the first question
    $form = $domCrawler->selectButton("Next »")->form();
    $form['question_1'] = 'A:0';
    $response = $this->client->submit($form);
    $this->assertRedirectedTo('style/discover/2');

    // Get the 5th question.
    $this->call('GET', 'style/discover/5');
    // BROKEN

    // Expect to be redirected to the 2nd question.
    $this->assertRedirectedTo('style/discover/2');
    $this->assertSessionHas('attention');
}
```

### Any ideas?

Do I need to reset something in order to make several calls? Is this bad practice for making several calls like this? Is there a better way to write this test? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Probable Solution:

Use `$this->client->restart()` to start a new request.

### Explanation/Detail:

OK so, here's the rabbit hole :D

1. Laravel `TestCase` extends [Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php)
2. [Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php) uses [Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Client](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Client.php) to make the fake requests.
3. [Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Client](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Client.php) extends [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php)
4. [Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php) extends abstract class [Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\ Client](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php)
5. Abstract class [Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\ Client](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php) has a method [restart()](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php#L511)

So, I believe in your case (I haven't personally tested this), you should be able to do the following:

```
/**
 * When the user skips questions they have not yet answered, the user 
 * should be redirected back to the first unanswered question.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testDiscoverSkipQuestions()
{
    // Get the first question.
    $domCrawler = $this->client->request('GET', 'style/discover');

    // Answer the first question
    $form = $domCrawler->selectButton("Next »")->form();
    $form['question_1'] = 'A:0';
    $response = $this->client->submit($form);
    $this->assertRedirectedTo('style/discover/2');

    // ******** Restart for new request ********
    $this->client->restart();

    // Get the 5th question.
    $this->call('GET', 'style/discover/5');
    // ******** SHOULD NOW WORK - call() is a proxy to $this->client->request(); ********

    // Expect to be redirected to the 2nd question.
    $this->assertRedirectedTo('style/discover/2');
    $this->assertSessionHas('attention');
}
```

**Note** that the call() method is [a proxy to using `$this->client->request()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php#L56)

Hope that helps! Don't be afraid to dig into code inheritances to see if a convenience method exists to do what you need - changes are it often already exists :D

### Improvement(?)

Note that these tests might lean more towards "integration tests" rather than "unit tests". Integration tests may be a better fit when used with continuous integration frameworks. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511337/how-to-perform-integration-testing-in-php) for some more info.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked perfectly. Also, I appreciate the nudge in the right direction regarding "integration tests". Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I'm still wondering however why do we need to call `restart()` on the client between consecutive requests. What is exactly going on behind the scenes that is causing all the trouble?

Comment: @cafonso You call restart to start a new HTTP request rather than add onto the existing one. (An HTTP request is represented by a PHP object that needs re-creating for a new HTTP request). It's not really a "problem" so much as accurately modeling that there are multiple HTTP requests in the process this is testing. Hope that makes sense!