# Multiple HTTP requests in Laravel 5 integration tests

Tags: php, integration-testing, laravel-5

We are developing our projects in Laravel 4. One of our integration tests performs two consecutive HTTP requests to the same controller:

```php
public function testFetchingPaginatedEntities() {
    $response = $this->call('GET', "foos?page=1&page_size=1");
    // assertions

    $response = $this->call('GET', "foos");
    // some more assertions
}
```

As you can see, the second request does not carry any query string parameters. However, we noticed that our controller was receiving `page` and `page_size` in both requests.

We were able to fix this by restarting the test client between calls (as explained in [Laravel 4 controller tests - ErrorException after too many $this->call() - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515563/laravel-4-controller-tests-errorexception-after-too-many-this-call-why)):

```php
public function testFetchingPaginatedEntities() {
    $response = $this->call('GET', "foos?page=1&page_size=1");
    // assertions

    $this->client->restart();

    $response = $this->call('GET', "foos");
    // some more assertions
}
```

We are now considering porting our project to Laravel 5, but it looks like `$this->client` is no longer available in tests since L5 no longer uses `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Client`.

Could anybody provide an alternative for resetting the test client? Or maybe a way to avoid restarting it at all?

Comment: Might be related to this - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6373 - i reported it a while ago - still not fixed.

Comment: Thank you, i'll keep an eye on it.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange fyi, I opened an issue in Github and it looks like they have already fixed it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/7380

Comment: @cafonso: so, this means that `$this->client->restart()` is not needed anymore?

Comment: @spacek33z Haven't really tried because we stayed on L4 for the time being, but yeah, it should not be needed anymore.

IIRC, this is the specific commit which fixed the issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/7861640f4d5c55b066f0ac5f017006d972e20b14

Answer (score 5):

```
$this->refreshApplication();
```

between calls solved the issue for me on Laravel 5.4.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're testing with sqlite `:memory:`